# Text marquee WinForms

Tags: winforms, scroll, marquee

I want to implement scrolling functionality in winforms.  I need text to scroll like a marquee, but from the bottom to the top.

How can I do that?

Comment: The user doesn't want scrolling....wants to have a marquee like functionality. Can someone edit the question?

Comment: Please Check this Link http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/windowsprogramming/text-scroll-effect-cs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague, but I think what you want to do is set AutoScroll=true on your form and scrolling will be automatically provided.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you want to do. (making a specific area scrollable)
You can do it this way:

- Create a form
- Drag a panel onto it.
- Set the panel docking...the way you want it
- Set AutoScroll = true for the panel(Eric has suggested this).
- Now drag any other control onto the
  the panel.

The panel area is now scrollable.

If you want to make the whole form scrollable then set AutoScroll = true for the form.

Comment: i want autoscrolling text i.e some lines will automatically moves from bottom to top repeatedly

Comment: you want marquee LIKE functionality?

Comment: You should state that in your question

Comment: sorry for the confusion. yes i need marquee type functionality only

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your comment to PK's answer, you'd need to simply code into a timer, or other method, to change the labels/controls Y (Or Top) value, decrementing it as required. Once it reaches -(control Height), change to (Form.Height)+(Control Height) and continue decrementing.

Comment: oh is it the only solution? any how thank you for your suggestion

Comment: There is no built-in control to provide this functionality.